# Bar plot Matplotlib : Date interval (xaxis) issue with twinx

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pycharm

I don't understand why my piece of code doesn't work. I would like to have an x axis with an interval of 1.

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Dates)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))
ax.bar(df['Dates'],
       df['Score'],
       color='blue',
       width=2)
date_form = DateFormatter("%d/%m/%Y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df['Dates'],
       df['Price'],
         color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `ax`'s date formatting just gets overridden by `ax2.plot`, so you should apply the date formatter to `ax2` instead of `ax`. Also [`autofmt_xdate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) is useful for rotating the date labels:

```py
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))
ax.bar(df['Dates'], df['Score'], color='blue', width=1)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df['Dates'], df['Price'], color='black')

# apply the date formatting to ax2 instead of ax
date_form = DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))

# rotate the date labels
fig.autofmt_xdate(ha='center', rotation=90)
```

This is the output with some random data (in the future it's recommended to paste data as text so we can directly copy the real data):

[image]